# opencv array more than 255

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm dealing with CvMat in opencv of type CV_8U.

I'm basically adding arrays (and resultant addition is expected to be more than 255).

It looks like the CvMat array doesn't store values more than 255 (values more than 10,000-20,000). I don't want an overflow to occur.

Is there any way I can do that using a opencv data-structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CV_8U means each variable is between 0 and 255 (8bit unsigned integer). 
CV_16U will give you 0 to 65535
Is that all you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use larger variable, like CV_16U or even 64 bit double.
Convert both matrices to the large variable and then apply your code.
Dont forget to rescale everything back to 0..255 before you convert it back to CV_8U