# how can i store a value more than 255 in a matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

i am trying to read a csv file and store it's values in a matrix. But the values in csv file exceeds 255.

So how can i store values more than 255. or is there another way to read and store values?

Comment: Use float or signed or unsigned 16/32 bit type. (for ex: CV_16UC1)

Comment: You are probably using an unsigned char data type. try using a float, int or double: http://ninghang.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html

Comment: my csv file contain 2810 rows and 6 columns. It contain x,y coordinates for the respective image file. 

how can i accesses the x,y coordinates from the csv file?

Comment: @DamithTilakaratne: That sound like a non-standard format. You will have to program it yourself. Luckily, "csv" is a fairly simple textformat, especially when the contents are just numbers. Just go ahead and start coding.

Comment: paste the code what you are currently having problem with. Some type of example would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [opencv array more than 255](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081773/opencv-array-more-than-255)

Comment: it depends on what type and range you need. The question is very ambiguous

Comment: What is the actual type of "a matrix"?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Mat of type 32F or type int. I dont know whats the max value that you are getting in the CSV, you can choose from any of the standard datatypes you think. Here is how you can access and load the values. The same method can be used to access/assign values from the CSV file. Obviously You will have to change the code a bit, since I have only shown the method.

```
cv::Mat_<int> img = cv::Mat_<int>::zeros(3,3);

for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        img.at<int>(r,c) = 300;
    }
}

std::cout<<img;
```